# How to disable UITableViewCell without disabling UIButtons inside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I know this is really easy question, and i checked almost every question in stackoverflow, but i couldn't find a proper solution.

I have a custom UITableViewCell,

I tried

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

and

```
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

already, but it still prevents the button inside of the cell being selected. I tried to implement several delegate methods, but still no luck.

I was hoping you guys can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to disable user interaction if you do want its buttons to respond to events?
Are you sure that what you want isn't do nothing in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: action?

Comment: I guess, I put the question wrong, i want to show my tableview's first cell not selectable, because wherever i tap, always my button gets into highlighted state, I only want to my button selected exactly when i tap to button.

Comment: Then I think that you should override the setHighlighted:animated: message from your custom cell and force a setHighlighted:NO to the button. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Assign the `UIButton`, the selector you want to perform as an action; in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and DO NOTHING in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Edit After Your Comment:

And put `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];` for `indexPath.row == 0`in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` That's it.

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing actually, but still i am getting the same result. If i do this, my button is still not getting into highlighted state. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why you want this behaviour but if u must need it, then why dont u add another view bellow the button which has every other views as subviews. Do not make button as the subview of the container you just created then disable that particular container view which does not have button. So that button will be enabled and all other views will be disabled.